# Google API payment - Android

Tags: android, google-api, ocr, android-library, google-vision

I added google OCR (Text detection) to my android app using gradle dependency.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.1'
```

In there pricing list they are saying for a month first 1000 requests are free but we have to pay for next requests.

i go through their tutorial guide to implement this.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#0

but there is no need to add google API KEY or any other identification and a payment method.

So how they count my requests. will they block my requests after exceeding the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Vision for Mobile works on device so there is no limit. 1000 requests limit is for Cloud Vision API